# Xcode crashes my laptop's media (spotify, etc) upon Simulator fully loading and build succeeding

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

How to resolve this bug? It's quite annoying.
The project that is being processed and built is just a simple app with 1 ViewController file, loading up 2 local videos onto a simple a application using AVPlayerLayer and adding it to the UIView.

***Laptop specs:***

Macbook Pro 15-inch Retina Mid-2014

OSX El Capitan, 10.11.3

2.5 GHz i7

16GB DDR3 RAM

NVIDIA GT 750m

**UPDATE:**

Upon further investigation it's the specific program that I am running that is causing the issue. Here is the code currently in the project, does anyone have a idea?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreGraphics

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    /****************************************
                 Initializers
    ****************************************/

    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var screenWidth: CGFloat { get{ return screenSize.width } }
    var screenHeight: CGFloat { get{ return screenSize.height } }
    var defaultCGRect: CGRect{ get{ return CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height) } }

    let profileView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let worldView = UIView()
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()

    /** Table setup **/
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    var tableData = [String]()

    /** Scroll setup **/
    var frame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(50, 300, 200, 50))


    /* size of color array determines page count, the lines commented with /!\ are where the number needs to be placed
    to correctly work */
    var colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]//, UIColor.yellowColor()]

    /****************************************
    ****************************************/

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /****************************************
               Update Relevant Initializers
        ****************************************/

        profileView.frame = defaultCGRect
        worldView.frame = defaultCGRect

        tableView.frame = defaultCGRect
        for index in 1...12 {
            self.tableData.append("Lesson \(index)")
        }
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
        tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        scrollView.frame = defaultCGRect
        scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        /***** Resources ****/


        /****************************************
        ****************************************/

        for index in 0..<colors.count {///!\

            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
            self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

            var subView = UIView(frame: frame)
            if index == 0{
                let parentLayer = CALayer()
                let playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = getVideoLayer("understand", frame: screenSize)
                let logoLayer = getImageLayer("logo_v5.1.png", center: true, opacity: 0.6)

                parentLayer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                parentLayer.addSublayer(logoLayer)

                profileView.frame = frame

                profileView.layer.addSublayer(parentLayer)
                subView = profileView
            }else if index == 1{
                var tableFrame = frame
                tableFrame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 24//change 24 to auto later
                tableView.frame = tableFrame
                subView = tableView
            }else{
                let parentLayer = CALayer()
                let playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = getVideoLayer("home", frame: screenSize)
                let logoLayer = getImageLayer("logo_v5.1.png", center: true, opacity: 0.6)

                parentLayer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                parentLayer.addSublayer(logoLayer)

                worldView.frame = frame

                worldView.layer.addSublayer(parentLayer)
                subView = worldView
            }

            self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)///!\
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changePage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    // MARK : TO CHANGE WHILE CLICKING ON PAGE CONTROL
    func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
        let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, 0), animated: true)
    }


    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }


    // UITableViewDataSource methods

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    // UITableViewDelegate methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return calculateHeight()
    }

    func calculateHeight() -> CGFloat {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
        {
            return CGFloat(100) // iPad
        } else {
            return CGFloat(53) // iPhone
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Item selected", message: "You selected item \(indexPath.row)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("An alert of type \(alert.style.hashValue) was tapped!")
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func getImageLayer(image: String, center: Bool, opacity: Float = 1.0) -> CALayer{
        let imageLayer = CALayer()
        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named:image)!
        imageLayer.contents = image.CGImage

        if center{
            var imageWidth: CGFloat { get{ return CGFloat(screenWidth-50) } }
            var imageHeight: CGFloat { get{ return CGFloat((screenHeight/2)-80) } }
            var centerX: CGFloat { get{ return CGFloat(screenWidth/2)-(imageWidth/2) } }
            var centerY: CGFloat { get{ return CGFloat(screenHeight/2)-((imageHeight/1.65)) } }
            imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(centerX, centerY, imageWidth, imageHeight)
        }

        imageLayer.opacity = opacity

        return imageLayer
    }

    func getVideoLayer(videoName: String, frame: CGRect) -> AVPlayerLayer{
        let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(videoName, withExtension: "mp4")!
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = frame
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        player.play()

        return playerLayer
    }
}
```

Debugger Window in Xcode, shows the build taking up 100mb of memory, but no sign of network usage...

**UPDATE 2:**

The following is the log from the console window in reference to the simulator. There seems to be multiple errors listed, but can someone help me understand what they mean.

```
Mar  4 23:02:32 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro nanoregistrylaunchd[3088]: Failed to enable path: code = 113: Could not find specified service, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/NanoLaunchDaemons/com.apple.NPKCompanionAgent.plist
Mar  4 23:02:32 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro nanoregistrylaunchd[3088]: Failed to enable path: code = 113: Could not find specified service, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/NanoLaunchDaemons/com.apple.pairedunlockd-phone.plist
Mar  4 23:02:32 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro calaccessd[3078]: table drop: 101
Mar  4 23:02:39 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[3036]: Weekly asset update check did fire (force=NO)
Mar  4 23:02:39 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[3036]: Beginning check for asset updates (force: 0
Mar  4 23:02:39 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[3036]: Did not complete check for asset updates (force: 0, isVoiceOverRunning: 0
Mar  4 23:03:01 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro lsd[3056]: LaunchServices: Currently 0 installed placeholders: (
    )
Mar  4 23:03:07 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3040]: assertion failed: 15D21 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
Mar  4 23:03:09 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar  4 23:03:09 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro mstreamd[3025]: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
Mar  4 23:03:09 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro mstreamd[3025]: (Note ) AS: : Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
Mar  4 23:03:09 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro mstreamd[3025]: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
Mar  4 23:03:12 Clarkes-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3040]: assertion failed: 15D21 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
```

Comment: first you have to check in AppDelegate method. Debug it by breakpoint. it might be some error. can you please Describe The error.

Comment: @Rushi Hi! I updated my post with a error log from the console window of the simulator, there seems to be multiple errors, but is it possible if you could help me understand what it is trying to tell me?